# API is not calling on first render, only after I manually re-render React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ocr, azure-ai

I am calling the Azure Optical Character Recognition API in my React app that requires an initial POST request to get an 'operation-location' value from the response header. The 'operation-location' value is then used to make a GET request.

The API takes an url to an image with text and returns the plain text from the image.

The issue I am facing is that the **POST request is only successful when I manually re-render the React app**. I submit this url https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1Abv.png via the UI I have created, both POST and GET requests fail but they will **only be successful when I hit ctrl + S on the development environment.**

When I log the 'operation-location' value on the first render, it returns null so the GET request is made to http://localhost:5173/null and so it fails. But, when I manually re-render the app by hitting save, both API calls are successful and the `getText` variable is rendered.

`getText` is a stateful variable that I am updating with the text from the image

I am trying to make it so it is successful on the first load.

On the first render, I get an error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'analyzeResult') when trying to resolve `.then((json)=> {` within the `getData` function

The POST request takes a user input in the body of the request from props.UserUrl which comes from the file Homepage.jsx:

```
import {React, useState} from 'react'
import Api from './Api';

export default function Homepage(props){
const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false)
const [input, setInput] = useState('');
const [text, setText] = useState('')

function handleChange (e) {
    setInput(e.target.value)
}

function handleClick(){
    setText(input)
    setIsClicked(true);

} 
        {if (isClicked == true){
            return (
                <div>
                     <Api UserUrl={text}/>
                </div>             
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <div className="image-input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder='enter url you want to convert' onChange={handleChange}/>
                    <button onClick={handleClick}>Submit</button>
                    </div>
                    )
        }
        }
```

}

The API is called in Api.jsx:

```
import { React, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Api(props) {
  // Need this unique value to send the GET request. We receive it from the POST request
  const [operationLocation, setOperationLocation] = useState(null);

 
  // We will add the text from the image to this variable
  const [getText, setGetText] = useState(null);

  const [userUrl, setUserUrl] = useState('');

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const [responseHeaders, setResponseHeaders] =useState ({})


  // We make a POST request to this URL
  let url = `${import.meta.env.VITE_ENDPOINT}.cognitiveservices.azure.com/vision/v3.2/read/analyze`;
  // Options for POST request
  const options = {
    // Change the image url to any you like that has text
    body: (JSON.stringify({ "url": props.UserUrl })),
    headers: {
      // Need to set this parameter or else won't work due to CORS
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE",
      // This is the value we need to get in the header request
      "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "operation-location",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY
    },
    method: "POST",
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: "same-origin"
  };


  // Options for Get request
  const optionsGet = {
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE",
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY
    },
    method: "GET",
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: "same-origin"
  };

  useEffect(()=> {
    // Post request
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true)
      fetch(url, options)
      // Setting the operation location value from the header
      .then((res) => {
        return setOperationLocation(res.headers.get('operation-location'))
      })   
      // On first render, operationLocation value is not being returned, returns null
       .then(console.log(operationLocation))
         }
        
        // Get request
      const getData = () => {
        // Passing the operation location value from the POST request into our GET request
        fetch(operationLocation, optionsGet)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.ok) {
            return res.json()
          }    
        })
        .then((json)=> {
          // The response returns an array of text. The text gets broken up into multiple lines
          const textArray = json.analyzeResult.readResults[0].lines;
          // Map through the response to get each individual text
          const textOutput = textArray.map(item => item.text) //returns an array
          // Use the join method to get rid of the commas in the array so it returns a string
          const textOutputString = textOutput.join(' ')
          setGetText(textOutputString)
  
          setLoading(false)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
        
      }  
    // Asyncrhonously make the requests. We need to wait for response from the POST request before we execute the GET request
      async function callApi () {

        await fetchData ()
        console.log('post request successful')
        console.log(operationLocation)
        await getData()
        console.log('get request succesful')
      setLoading(false)
    } 
      callApi();
  
  }, [props.UserUrl])
  
  // We check to see if the request has populate state and then we render the response
  if (loading) {
      return (
       <div>
        Loading...
       </div>
      )} else {
        return (
           <div className="center">
        <p>{getText}</p>
      <p>{props.UserUrl}</p>
    </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

**What I have tried:**

- The url for the POST request is correct because it will render successfully in its second render. I have moved it to a .env variable because the endpoint is sensitive
- I have tried to make the GET request asynchronous but I am not sure if GET request is being made before the POST request is successful. On checking the network tab, it looks like the POST request takes 956ms to be successful.
- I don't think it's a CORS problem because I have set the mode to CORS and also I have used an Edge plugin to disable CORS and I was still having the same problem
- I have tried using a stateful variable called `loading` to re-render React on API call but still facing same issue of it only working on a manual re-render
- I have tried using a stateful variable called `data` to re-render React on API call but still facing same issue of it only working on a manual re-render
- I tried using `props.UserUrl` as a stateful variable but was running into an endless loop
- I have tried using a stateful variable to capture the `responseHeaders` to force the API to re-render but I was still facing the same issues
- I added `operationLocation` value to the useEffect array but it created an endless loop
- I have tried using `location.reload()` to re-render React but it just reloaded back to the initial UI and lost the data

I think I need to force React to re-render someway but I don't know how.

**Edit: Solution**

The problem was that I was using `operationLocation` in state which meant it was not updating on the first render. It meant that on the first render, the value was null and so the `getData` method was making a request to null.

By declaring `operationLocation` as a non stateful variable and hoisting it, I mutate its value in the `fetchData` method.

I looked again at the JavaScript SDK for this API from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/client-library?pivots=programming-language-javascript&tabs=visual-studio

It mentions using a while loop that waits for the text to be read. Instead of using this, I used a `setTimeout` function when calling `getData` so that it is being called after the text from the image has been read.

See the API code here:

```
import { React, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Api(props) {

  let operationLocation;

  // We will add the text from the image to this variable
  const [getText, setGetText] = useState(null);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const [resStatusForGetReq, setStatusForGetReq] = useState()


  // We make a POST request to this URL
  let url = `${import.meta.env.VITE_ENDPOINT}.cognitiveservices.azure.com/vision/v3.2/read/analyze`;
  // Options for POST request
  const options = {
    // Change the image url to any you like that has text
    body: (JSON.stringify({ "url": props.UserUrl })),
    headers: {
      // Need to set this parameter or else won't work due to CORS
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE",
      // This is the value we need to get in the header request
      "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "operation-location",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY
    },
    method: "POST",
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: "same-origin"
  };


  // Options for Get request
  const optionsGet = {
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE",
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY
    },
    method: "GET",
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: "same-origin"
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Post request
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true)

        fetch(url, options)
          // Setting the operation location value from the header
          .then((res) => {       
            return operationLocation = (res.headers.get('operation-location'))     
          })

    }

    // Get request
    const getData = async () => {
      console.log(operationLocation)
      // Passing the operation location value from the POST request into our GET request
      fetch(operationLocation, optionsGet)
        .then((res) => {
          setStatusForGetReq(res.status)
          if (res.ok) {
            return res.json()
          }
        })
        .then((json) => {
          // The response returns an array of text. The text gets broken up into multiple lines
          const textArray = json.analyzeResult.readResults[0].lines;
          // Map through the response to get each individual text
          const textOutput = textArray.map(item => item.text) //returns an array
          // Use the join method to get rid of the commas in the array so it returns a string
          const textOutputString = textOutput.join(' ')
          setGetText(textOutputString)

          setLoading(false)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })

    }
    // Asyncrhonously make the requests. We need to wait for response from the POST request before we execute the GET request
    async function callApi() {
        fetchData()
      console.log('post request successful')
      // Need to wait for read response before we call the GET request
      setTimeout(()=> {
        getData()
      }, 2000)
        

      console.log('get request succesful')

    }
    callApi();

  }, [])

  // We check to see if the request has populate state and then we render the response
  if (loading) {
    return (
      <div>
        Loading...

      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="center">
        <p>{getText}</p>
        <p>{props.UserUrl}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the POST request in another useEffect with no dependency so the useEffect will run only once when the app load first time

```
 useEffect(()=> {
    // Post request
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true)
      fetch(url, options)
      // Setting the operation location value from the header
      .then((res) => {
        return setOperationLocation(res.headers.get('operation-location'))
      })   
      // On first render, operationLocation value is not being returned, returns null
       .then(console.log(operationLocation))
         }
  
  }, [])


 useEffect(()=> {
        // Get request
      const getData = () => {
        // Passing the operation location value from the POST request into our GET request
        fetch(operationLocation, optionsGet)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.ok) {
            return res.json()
          }    
        })
        .then((json)=> {
          // The response returns an array of text. The text gets broken up into multiple lines
          const textArray = json.analyzeResult.readResults[0].lines;
          // Map through the response to get each individual text
          const textOutput = textArray.map(item => item.text) //returns an array
          // Use the join method to get rid of the commas in the array so it returns a string
          const textOutputString = textOutput.join(' ')
          setGetText(textOutputString)
  
          setLoading(false)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
        
      }  
    // Asyncrhonously make the requests. We need to wait for response from the POST request before we execute the GET request
      async function callApi () {

        await fetchData ()
        console.log('post request successful')
        console.log(operationLocation)
        await getData()
        console.log('get request succesful')
      setLoading(false)
    } 
      callApi();
  
  }, [props.UserUrl])
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I was still facing the same issue. I checked the JavaScript SDK for the Azure service and managed to solve it
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/client-library?pivots=programming-language-javascript&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: The problem was that the `operationLocation` variable was not updating on the first render, so I have declared it as a non-stateful variable. I also put the `getData` method in a `setTimeout` function to be called after 1000ms